# What to do when Tomcat is looking for a resource in another deployed application?

Tags: java, tomcat

I have two applications under tomcat/webapps and appOne is trying to find a resource in appTwo subfolders.

I saw in logs/catalina.out that Tomcat does not find a resource /pages/templates/email-message.xhtml (which really exists under appOne subfolder).

Error log:

> com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute #{action.sendEmail}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: resource doesn't exist: /pages/templates/email-message.xhtml

If I copy the resource appOne/pages/templates/email-template.xhtml to appTwo/pages/templates/ (where I actually have others templates), Tomcat will find the resource.

What should I do?

[Edit 1]:

- I'm able to log in on both applications and this seems ok.
- I do not want to share any resources between those applications.
- I want appOne and appTwo using its own /pages/templates/
- If I delete appTwo and restart Tomcat, appOne will finally use its own /pages/templates/.
- It seems that something is not isolated enough.

Comment: You should expose the resource of app1 as a service for app2. Applications should not depend on directly accessing the resources of other applications. It's a bad practice.

Comment: @MaxG I totally agree! And I actually do not want any dependency between them. I added some more details and I hope it will make my problem clearer.

Comment: Maybe you should put the resources in the application classpath and use some kind of class path loader instead of putting the resource in the tomcat public resource dir?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's a question of why it's in the other application.
Do they both use it, or is it just in the wrong application.

If it's in the wrong application, just move it.

If both use it, you have at least two choices.

The easy answer is to copy the template to the application that's missing it.

The potential downside is that you now have two copies of the template, and if you need to keep them the same, then you have a maintenance challenge.

The less easy answer is to figure out a way have the one application access the other application's resources. In a full-blown Java EE server, you could bundle both apps into a .ear file, and give one access to the other, but Tomcat doesn't support .ear files...

If it's just the one file, I'd just copy it.
But keep an eye on the project - if you start needing to do this with lots of files (whatever your definition of 'lots' is), then you should figure out a way to share resources.

Comment: I do not want any dependency between them. I added some more details and I hope it will make my problem clearer. Thank you!